# Excel 2010 VBA macro adjust to do all rows 1-by-1 down to the last row (14000 rows)

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

Right now the macro does the following:
1. Selects entire row. 2. Sorts sideways (left to right). 3. Goes to the next row. (And is ready for me to do Ctrl+s and make it run again on the next row. Which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid because I have to do 14000 rows).

How do I modify the code to do the same thing all the way down from row 1, to row number 14000? (I don't want it to check row by row if there is some content because that'll slow down the code. I'd rather hard code the row number to 14000 right now, and then change it manually as needed).

---

```
Sub SortingOneByOne()
'
' SortingOneByOne Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveCell.Range _
        ("A1:AEA1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SetRange ActiveCell.Range("1:1")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

---

I found this code which seems to do just that, but I don't know how to have the 2 codes work together:

```
Sub FindEmptyCell_2() 
Dim i As Integer 
Do 
i = i + 1 
Loop Until IsEmpty(Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value) 
Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Select 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, rw As Range

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each rw In sht.UsedRange.Rows
        With sht.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=rw, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                            Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange rw
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to error at `With sht.Sort` I think you have to sort on a range.

Comment: Worked for me in testing.

Comment: I get `Compile Error: Method or data member not found` on that line. Strange.... I use Excel 2003, maybe it's something related to that.

Answer (score 0):

To modify your code as little as possible you can just use this:

```
Sub SortingOneByOne()
'
' SortingOneByOne Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'

 For x = 1 to 14000 'From Row 1 to 14000
    ActiveCell.Rows(x).EntireRow.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveCell.Range _
        ("A" & x & ":AEA" & x), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SetRange ActiveCell.Range(x)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Next x
End Sub
```